# How do you remove the desktop bookmark in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

All I want to do is remove the Desktop bookmark on the left-hand side of the nautilus window. I am using the latest Ubuntu 16.04, Xenial.

I've tried modifying the .config user-dirs file as well as the user-dirs.default file (as I am aware both need to be changed at the same time for the changes to work). I was able to rid myself of all the other bookmarks I don't need but even by commenting out desktop line, still no progress towards removing the desktop bookmark.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure you can remove that. After all the file manager is the one managing and populating your Desktop.

Comment: Even removing the Desktop folder itself does not remove it from the sidebar. Looks like a hardcoded thing

Comment: After changing both user-dirs files and removing the desktop folder from my home folder, I now get an error that says can not find file location when I click on the desktop bookmark so I am more eager than ever to rid myself of it. 
Anyone know where it is hard-coded? Maybe I can go in there and work a little magic.

Comment: @DanielBarenboim https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus is the source code. Simply comment out the lines that display the `bookmark` and recompile it. Removing something is infinitely easier than creating something new.

Comment: rip me, I want to add it back and I see  "removing something is infinitely easier than creating something new"