# Remove bookmarks in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I would like to remove the pictures, videos, and music shortcuts.

I have done some web searches and searches on this site but I have not been able to find an answer that works.

I followed some instructions (see link below), which involved editing these 2 files:

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults
```

[How to remove unwanted default bookmarks in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762591/how-to-remove-unwanted-default-bookmarks-in-nautilus)

However, the shortcuts still show in nautilus, just further down on the list (underneath the trash).

I also see this solution but does that mean recompiling the operating system?
[How do you remove the desktop bookmark in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840057/how-do-you-remove-the-desktop-bookmark-in-nautilus)

Comment: Have you tried deleting them from the trash?

Answer (score 3):

I think you will just have to remove the file

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

You can also edit the file and just remove single entries.

Comment: This solution worked for me if I also (as suggested in other answers) commented out `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and created a `~/.config/user-dirs.conf` containing `enabled=false`